# Properly convert raw href with variable to jstl c:url

Tags: javascript, html, jstl

I'm maintaining a small jsp/html/javascript app with a Spring backend.  I didn't write it, and much of it was done in a way that I would never have done myself.  I don't want to rewrite it, and I don't need to, but I may need to fix small quality issues now and then.

The original app was written with all the web pages having a hardcoded reference to the context root (the name of the application).  I thought I fixed all of those to use proper JSTL "c:url" references, but I missed one, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to properly convert it.

I'm going to paste the relevant line of code here.  All that really matters is the "a" tag and the "href" attribute.  The wider context the line is used in is sort of odd and hacky, but it does work:

```
r[++j] ='<tr bgcolor=\"Moccasin\" align=\"Center\" text-decoration=\"none\"><td><a style=\"color:blue;text-align:center\" href=\"/estimator/search/projEstimate/GetProjectEstimate/' + projects[key].projectAppId + '\">';
```

This intends to produce a relative url like "/search/projEstimate/GetProjectEstimate/xxxx", where "xxxx" is the value of "projects[key].projectAppId".  For now, the name of the root context, "estimator", is hardcoded in the url.

Again, this works as written, but I want to remove the root context reference, most likely by using a JSTL "c:url" reference, but I don't understand exactly how to convert this, especially with the complication of the variable portion of the url.

Comment: How did you use the `c:url` tag so far? Could you please add an example?

Comment: Sorry, I've managed to resolve this, and I haven't reported back here yet. Using c:url was easier than I thought, I just had to get quotes right.